# Why won't my strokes render color correctly (Cycles)?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, video-sequence-editor, grease-pencil

[image]

This is what it looks like rendered in the 3d Viewport
[image: skater]

This is the VSE.  If I render I get the same dull colors on the stroke.
[image: skaterVSE]
Finally, here's a setting I tweaked to get close to the correct color, but I think I'm barking up the wrong tree...
[image: skater2VSE]

Comment: can u provide a simplified blend file so we can check it out?

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/b/GKvDLnoB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Grease Pencil remove Use Lights option, In this case line will not be affected by light (which you don't have) and it will use original color:

[image]

Comment: That did it!  Thank you, this was driving me crazy.